# How can I iterate an array with .map in Javascript?

Tags: array.prototype.map

I have a canvas, the size of it 600 x 400px. I would like to draw a line from its edge at every 20px. I have created the x and y coordinates of each point into 2 arrays, x and y. Now i would like to return the value of each, then insert it into a path to draw a line to the center of canvas. the canvas center is 300, 200px.

Here i create the 2 coordinates:

```
let x = [];
let y = [];
for (let i=0; i<=600; i+=20) {
  x.push(i);
}
for (let i=0; i<=400; i+=20) {
  y.push(i);
}
```

I have read about the .map but i couldnt apply it correctly. How could i solve it?

Once i have those values, I would like to read each x value and pair it with a y value on the canvas.

then i would like to insert these values into

```
ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(x, y);
   ctx.lineTo(300, 200);
```

Your feedback is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.map is used to iterate over a collection (e.g. [1,2,3,4]). You could do it like in the following:

```
let x = [];
let y = [];
for (let i=0; i<=600; i+=20) {
  x.push(i);
}
for (let i=0; i<=400; i+=20) {
  y.push(i);
}

y.map(coord => console.log(coord))
```

Reference material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Please include the code as text, not as a screenshot.